# How to compare 2D array values with the user input?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have written a code which should prompt the user to enter a number and then according to that number, they will be asked (Please enter a number between 1 and 4)* the number the user chose. Then, their input will be compared to see if there is any match in the 2D array(Rows or columns).

- Please enter a number: (for ex. **2**)
- Please enter a number between 1 and 4: **3**
- Please enter a number between 1 and 4: **1**

Here is your grid:
(2x2 grid filled filled with random numbers)

The program then should look if there is any match between the 2D array and the users numbers (in this case: 3 & 1), if they get a match, a message should output: Well done, if no match, Bad luck.

I already did everything but I am completely stuck at the comparing step, I spent way to long trying to figure it out, but this what I got to up till now

```
 4  2  4
 3  1  1
 4  3  3
```

---

Here is a sample of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int Atemp = 0;
int Utemp = 0;
double Working = 0;
double Total = 0;
char Answer = 'x';
int Umain;
const int maxNum = 2;
int intArray[maxNum];



void printGrid(int &Umain);

void fillIntArray(int array[], int size);
void reverseArray(int array[], int size);
void outputIntArray(int array[], int n);

bool compareGrid(int intArray[], int &Atemp, size_t rows, size_t cols, size_t n);


int main(){



    cout << "Please Enter numbers between 1 and 12: ";
    cin >> Umain;


    do{
       if(Umain <=12){
        fillIntArray(intArray, maxNum);
        //outputIntArray(intArray, maxNum);
        printGrid(Umain);
       }
    }while (Answer == 'y');

    compareGrid(intArray, Atemp);



    return 0;
}

void displayOverview(){

}


void fillIntArray(int array[], int size){

    do{
    for (Utemp = Umain; Utemp > 0; Utemp--){
      cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 4: ";
      cin >> Atemp;
    }
    }while (Answer == 'y');
}

/*
void outputIntArray(int array[], int Atemp){
    for(int i = 0; i < Atemp; i++){
        printf("%d", array[i]);
    }
}
*/

void printGrid(int &Umain){

  cout<<endl;
    cout<<" ";
        int i=1,j;
        for(j = 0; j <= 4*Umain; j++){
            if(j%4==2){
                cout<<" ";
            }
        }

  cout<<endl;
    for(i = 0; i <= 2*Umain; i++){
        for(j = 0; j <= 2*Umain; j++){
            if(i%2==0){
                if(j==0){
                    cout<<" ";
                    }
                if(j%2==0){
                    cout<<" ";
            }else{
                    cout<<"---";
                }
            }else{
                if(j%2==0){
                    cout<<" | ";
                }else cout<< (rand()%4+1);
            }
        }
        if(i%2!=0){
                cout<<" ";
            }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<" ";

        for(j = 0, i = 1; j <= 4*Umain; j++){
            if(j%4==2){
                cout<< " ";
            }
        }
    cout<<endl;
    }

bool compareGrid(int intArray[], int &Atemp, size_t rows, size_t cols, size_t n) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i ++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; j ++) {
      for (size_t k = 0; k < n; k ++) {
        if (intArray[i][j] == Atemp[k]) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: How do you define a match?

Comment: As @ggorlen said, do both numbers need to be in the array for a match?

Comment: Doesn't look like your code would compile.  Could you include a main() and the #include statements so that others can, cut, paste, and compile without any modifications?

Comment: Sorry, hope it it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are not populating `intArray` with any values
- `intArray` is not scoped to be available to `compareGrid`, it must be passed as a parameter.
- `void compareGrid` conflicts with `bool compareGrid`, the prototype must match the definition.
- `Atemp` is an `int`, not an array, so trying to access an element (`Atemp[i]`) is undefined and disallowed by the compiler.
- `intArray` is a one dimensional array in memory that you are trying to access a second index of with `intArray[i][j]` which is similarly undefined and disallowed. If you want it to be represented as a two dimensional array then without knowing the dimensions of the array at compile time (or at least all but the first) you need to use a dynamic array, an `int**` in this case. Alternatively, if you want to store the 2D array as a 1D array in memory then the indexing must be done `intArray[i * rows + j]`.

If you use the former, then `compareGrid` becomes

```
bool compareGrid(int** intArray, int &Atemp) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {   // i ++ instead of ++i because ++i will skip
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 4; j ++) { // first row, similarly ++j will skip first column
      if (intArray[i][j] == Atemp) {
        return true;      // return true only if match is found
      }
    }
  }
  return false;           // otherwise return false
}
```

But notice that you must compare each input on its own, instead of waiting until all inputs have been gathered, if you need to wait until all inputs are gathered then you would have to store them to an array (you can still use `Atemp` but it will have to an array of `int`s) but you will also need to pass the dimension of `Atemp`, i.e.

```
bool compareGrid(int** intArray, int* Atemp, size_t n) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 4; j ++) {
      for (size_t k = 0; k < n; k ++) {
        if (intArray[i][j] == Atemp[k]) {
          return true;       // Again, return true only when a match is found
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;              // This statement is ONLY reached if there are no matches
}
```

Of course if you don't know the dimensions of `intArray` at compile time (which it appears you do not) then you must pass those as well -

```
bool compareGrid(int** intArray, int* Atemp, size_t rows, size_t cols, size_t n) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i ++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; j ++) {
      for (size_t k = 0; k < n; k ++) {
        if (intArray[i][j] == Atemp[k]) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Where you can substitute `intArray[i * rows + j]` for `intArray[i][j]` if you need to use 1D array to represent the 2D array.

---

#### Note

None of those comparison methods will work if you do not populate `intArray` with values in `fillIntArray`, something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
  intArray[i] = value;      // Where {value} is an integer
}
```

or for `int**`,

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i ++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < cols; j ++) {
    intArray[i][j] = value; 
  }
}
```

in place of the line

```
for (int i = Atemp; i < Atemp; i ++);
```

which is a useless statement that does nothing but effectively check if `Atemp < Atemp` (always false - no loop).

---

#### Additional note

If you use a dynamic 2D array (`int**`) then you can initialize it with the following

```
int** intArray = new int*[rows];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i ++) {
  intArray[i] = new int[cols];
}
```

where in your case `rows == cols`, which is obviously not always the case.

Hope this helps

Comment: I truly thank you for your effort and thanks for explaining it for me. However, I am trying to call this function in my main, its giving me an error cannot convert int* to int**, what does this mean?. Thank you again.

Comment: That means you have something that was initialized as an `int*` but is trying to be  passed to the function where an `int**` is required. My guess is you are still trying to use a 1D array for `intArray`, which is a perfectly fine way to do it, but that means you need to change `bool compareGrid(int** intArray...` to `bool compareGrid(int intArray[]...` or `bool compareGrid(int* intArray...`and then change the indexing from `intArray[i][j]` to `intArray[i*rows + j]` where `rows` is the number of rows of the array. Update your question with your current code and I can give more complete answer.

Comment: Okay for sure !! :D

Comment: Alright, updated the code, please explain what my mistakes are, thanks in advance

Comment: So in `compareGrid` you are passing `intArray` as a 1D array by `compareGrid(int intArray[]...`, if you do that then the indexing in the line `if (intArray[i][j] == Atemp[k])` can't be done that way, _if_ you want to use a 1D array then this must be `if (intArray[i*rows + j] == Atemp[k])`. But there is another problem, `Atemp` is an `int`, not an array of `int`s, so if you try to access `Atemp[k]` it will cause an error. If you want to store all the user inputs to `Atemp` then `Atemp` must be an array of `int`s. If you want to compare each input when the user enters it then call ...

Comment: ... `compareGrid` during your input loop after each valid input.

Comment: what does this mean ?? error: invalid types 'int[size_t {aka unsigned int}]' for array subscript|

Comment: That means you are treating something that is not an array like it is an array but trying to access and element with array indexing, I would guess the problem is with `Atemp` Is still an `int` not an array of `int`s but you are using `Atemp[k]`

Comment: I am sorry, I am confused, how do I fix this issue?